# QML, Keeping the position while zooming into a ListView

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I am stuck on an issue regarding zooming into a ListView for multiple days now. I hope someone here might have a solution or an idea.

I have a ListView (with the id `pageView`) that has a model of images. The ListView has a property `defaultPageHeight` which indicates the default height of each image. It also has a `zoomFactor` property, that is default initialized to `1`.
The `height` of each delegate is set to:

```
height: Math.round(pageView.defaultPageHeight * pageView.zoomFactor)
```

I have overwritten the `onWheel` event of my `ListView` so that I can handle it manually. When I press `CTRL+Scroll` the `zoom(factor)` function is called, with a `factor` parameter that indicates how much to zoom.

The zooms function looks like this:

```
function zoom(factor)
{
    let newZoomFactor = pageView.zoomFactor * factor;
    let newPageHeight = Math.round(pageView.defaultPageHeight * newZoomFactor);
    
    // Make sure to store the position the listview was looking at before zooming
    let currentPageHeight = Math.round(pageView.defaultPageHeight * pageView.zoomFactor);
    let currentPageNumber = /*Gets the current page*/;
    let currentPos = pageView.contentY - pageView.originY;
    
    // Get the offset, meaning how far is the position away from the current page's top
    let pageOffset = currentPos - (currentPageHeight * currentPageNumber);
    
    // Apply the new zoom
    pageView.zoomFactor = newZoomFactor;

    // Set the new contentY
    pageView.contentY = newPageHeight * currentPageNumber + Math.round(pageOffset * newZoomFactor) + pageView.originY;
}
```

The zooming itself works fine, but I am not able to restore the position of the ListView before the zoom. So when I am zooming, I am also moving up or down in the listview for some reason.

You can see an example oft this in the following: https://imgur.com/a/cO4cAxq
As you can see, the ListView is successfully zooming, but it is changing its position. I'd like it to zoom into the middle of the screen, instead of moving around the document while zooming.

I have set up a simple, minimal replica of this so that you can test it out locally. This is how it looks: https://imgur.com/a/acUmjjx
You again see that it is zooming successfully, but moving across the ListView instead of zooming onto one point. Here is the code of the minimal replica: https://gist.github.com/DavidLazarescu/337d8b28e941cdbe6db3d4873ae45fd3

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a problem with originY. After recording some data of zooming I noticed that that setting `pageView.zoomFactor = newZoomFactor;` did not cause `originY` to refresh, so I was setting:

```
pageView.contentY = newPageHeight * currentPageNumber + Math.round(pageOffset * newZoomFactor) + pageView.originY;
```

while `originY` was the old `originY` and so I moved to a position that was `originY` away from where it should actually be.
To refresh `originY` before I was calculating the new position, I needed to call `pageView.forceLayout();` so that I can use the updated `originY` to calculate the actual position.

EDIT: I have updated the gist to contain the fix.

Answer (score 0):

[REWRITE]

I had a reattempt and found that ListView and GridView do a similar thing, but, feel that GridView is possibly better because it forewarns what all the children cells will be.

The other thing I found is that contentY AND originY is needed to determine the scroll position. If you use contentY alone, there will be an unaccountable drifting that occurs that eventually puts your zooming out of what. To understand it simply, the equation is approximately:

```
currentIndex = (currentY - originY) / cellHeight
```

and

```
currentY = currentIndex * cellHeight + originY
```

Without it, you may try to assume originY === 0 and get some creeping in zooming problems.

Here's my implementation with GridView:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    GridView {
        id: pageView
        property int defaultCellHeight: 400
        cellHeight: defaultCellHeight
        cellWidth: Math.round(cellHeight * 0.7)
        height: parent.height
        width: cellWidth
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        clip: true
        model: 500
        delegate: Rectangle
        {
            height: pageView.cellHeight
            width: pageView.cellWidth
            color: modelData % 2 == 0 ? "gray" : "green"
            border.color: GridView.isCurrentItem ? "black" : "transparent"
            border.width: 5
            Label
            {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.bold: true
                font.pointSize: 20 * (pageView.cellHeight / 400)
                text: modelData
            }
        }
        WheelHandler {
            acceptedModifiers: Qt.ShiftModifier
            onWheel: event => {
                let currentIndex = (pageView.contentY - pageView.originY + pageView.height / 2) / pageView.cellHeight - 1/2;
                let newCellHeight = Math.round(pageView.cellHeight * Math.pow(1.001, event.pixelDelta.y));
                pageView.cellHeight = newCellHeight;
                pageView.contentY = (currentIndex + 1 / 2) * newCellHeight - pageView.height / 2 + pageView.originY;
                event.accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: I have tried setting `highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange` but it messes with the scrolling behavior (Its only possible to scroll full pages). Tracking `currentIndex` manually also works, but it doesn't fix my problem. See how it looks here: https://imgur.com/a/XPU49EO

Comment: @Creapermann I have updated the code snippet to reflect the look and feel of your minimal example. However, I made a complete transition to (1) highlightRangeMode, (2) WheelHandler. The highlightRangeMode can take care of panning to exact intervals of items and can auto center the item if you set the related preferredHighlightBegin/preferredHighlightEnd properties. Also I replaced your MouseArea with WheelHandler because MouseArea clashes with the ListView scrolling.

Comment: Thank you, zooming works fine in the code you provided, but is it possible to not restrict the movement in the ListView to always have an item centered? I want to be able to move in freely in the ListView while zooming into the middle of the screen (`pageView.height/ 2`)

Comment: For example, try opening a PDF in firefox (or what ever browser you are using) and scroll through it and zoom into it. This is exactly the behavior I want to replicate.

Comment: Added a two ListView solution to solve the panning problem.

Comment: This works better than before, but the zooming is now jumping to center a page: https://imgur.com/a/HKyjl4Z. Do you have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have rewritten the answer using (1) GridView, (2) a new formula that uses both contentY and originY.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried GridView in the past as well though, but I was forced to switch back to ListView, since I didn't manage to enable horizontal flicking, when `conentWidth > pageView.height`. Do you know if this is possible with GridView?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this modification to your onWheel event (positionViewatIndex)

```
onWheel: {event => {
            let currentIndex = (pageView.contentY - pageView.originY + pageView.height / 2) / pageView.cellHeight - 1/2;
pageView.positionViewatIndex(currentIndex,ListView.Beginning)}
```

Comment: The formula returns currentIndex as a double precision not an integer. It's because it's a double precision number is why we wish to return back to that position after zoom operations, so, positionViewAtItem, I don't think will help.